# How to add postponed holidays in NETWORKDAYS or how to improve the formula so it counts workdays that are on weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a vacation excel where the worker vacations are calculated. My country has postponed holidays where we have to work on weekends. I was wondering if it is possible to add a list as I did with holidays in the NETWORKDAYS formula. How can I make an excel formula that if sees a date in a list that is between 2 dates to add it automatically (count as a workday) so I don't have to do it manually?
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say column E is where you have your extra working days list. Then you'll have

```
=NETWORKDAYS(start_date,end_date) + COUNTIFS(E:E,">="&start_date,E:E,"<="&end_date)
```